# How can I return multiple elements in a cell?

Tags: swift, parse-platform, tableview

I would like to return multiple elements of a cell. How can I do it? This is the code I'm working on

```
//
//  TableViewControllerCompiti.swift
//  Secondo B
//
//  Created by Edoardo on 23/12/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 ERC. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Parse

class TableViewControllerCompiti: UITableViewController {

var selfTable: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

@IBOutlet var MessageTable: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var Compiti: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var DescrizioneCompiti: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var DataCompiti: UILabel!

var messagesArray: [String] = [String]()
var descriptionArray: [String] = [String]()
var dateArray: [String] = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    func retrieveMessages() {

        let query = PFQuery(className: "Compiti")

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (remoteObjects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            for messageObject in remoteObjects! {

                let messageText: String? = (messageObject as PFObject) ["Materia"] as? String
                let descriptionText: String? = (messageObject as PFObject) ["Compiti"] as? String
                let date: String? = (messageObject as PFObject) ["Data"] as? String

                if messageText != nil {

                    self.messagesArray.append(messageText!)

                }

                if descriptionText != nil {

                    self.descriptionArray.append(descriptionText!)

                }

                if date != nil {

                    self.dateArray.append(date!)

                }
            }

            self.MessageTable.reloadData()

        }
    }

    retrieveMessages()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = UITableViewCell?()
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")

    Compiti.text = self.messagesArray[indexPath.row]
    DataCompiti.text = self.dateArray[indexPath.row]
    DescrizioneCompiti.text = self.descriptionArray[indexPath.row]

    if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: "ReUseCell")
        }

    return cell!
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return self.messagesArray.count
    }
}
```

When I run it, the simulator just returns a bunch of empty cells. How can I do to return the elements?

Comment: How many prototype cells do you have? And what is their reusable identifiers? Do you have a custom class for the cell? Also, you should not have a function inside `viewDidLoad`

Comment: I'm getting info from Parse, so the number of cells depends on the number of rows in Parse's database. Their reusable identifier is `cell`. And no, I don't have any custom class. @alaphao

Comment: The `Compti`, `DescrizioneCompiti` and `DataCompiti` are components inside your prototype cell right? First of all, you should create a custom `tableViewCell` and connect the outlets to the custom cell you created, not on viewcontroller.

Comment: What is the value of `self.messagesArray.count` when you return number of rows?  (You would be better to have one array of objects, with each object containing three strings, instead of three arrays of strings.  Imagine what happens if you get message text that has no matching description!)

Comment: Can you tell me please (in the answers) how can I do it? @PhillipMills

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Remark From your code:**

- you cannot implement and call the function inside of viewDidLoad(), you implement all functions/methods outside of the life cycle then call inside.
- I don't think its a good idea of having three different arrays to contain your data,you should learn `struct` or `class` **data structures** to group your data since you are getting them from the same class.

  ```
  struct myDataContainer
  {
      var message:String?
      var descriptionText:String?
      var date:String?
  }

   var arrayOfContainers = [myDataContainer]()  //<-- this will be your new array
  ```
- I saw that you had a customize cell where you wanted to have 2 Labels and UITextView.. you should create a subclass of UITableViewCell then group them inside.

  ```
        class CustomizeCell :UITableViewCell
        {
              @IBOutlet weak var Compiti: UILabel!
              @IBOutlet weak var DescrizioneCompiti: UITextView!
               @IBOutlet weak var DataCompiti: UILabel!

        } //<--- Subclass of UITableViewCell above


        struct myDataContainer
          {
             var message:String?
             var descriptionText:String?
             var date:String?
          }

  class TableViewControllerCompiti: UITableViewController {



  var arrayOfContainers = [myDataContainer]()  //<-- this will be your new array


  override func viewDidLoad()
  {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      retrieveMessages()   //<--- call function
  }

  func retrieveMessages()
  {
      var objectT = myDataContainer()
      let query = PFQuery(className: "Compiti")
      query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

          if let remoteObjects = objects
          {
              for messageObject in remoteObjects
              {
                  let messageText = messageObject["Materia"]  as? String
                  let description = messageObject["Compiti"]  as? String
                  let date        = messageObject["Data"]     as? String

                      objectT.message = messageText!
                      objectT.descriptionText = description!
                      objectT.date = date!

                      self.arrayOfContainers.append(objectT)

              }
              self.tableView.reloadData()
          }
      }
  }


  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomizeCell
      // as! CustomizeCell technically speaking make sure that we access our customize cell

      let data = self.arrayOfContainers[indexPath.row]
      cell.Compiti.text = data.message
      cell.DataCompiti.text = data.descriptionText
      cell.DescrizioneCompiti.text = data.date

      return cell
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return self.arrayOfContainers.count
       }
     }
  ```

Comment: This code gave my a `Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1` error. What did I do wrong? @Lamar

Comment: They are in the question @Lamar

Comment: It is the last image @Lamar